# Java, using a variable within classes

Tags: java, variables, global-variables

How can I use the variable drawMax in a different class?

```
public int DrawNumberSetting (int drawMax)
{
    System.out.print ("Please enter the maximum number of draws you want to play: ");
    drawMax = scan.nextInt ();
    return drawMax;
}
```

Comment: you mean to say that you want to use a local method variable in another class? Please elaborate.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I just want to use the value the user entered in this method, in another class I have. Is that possible?

Comment: why don't you try it out by your self.

Comment: Just provide drawMax to the other method. Really, can't get the point of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your drawNumberSetting(int drawMax) is declared in class A. That means that any other class that has an instance of class A can call that method and use the returned value.

```
class B
{
    public void my otherMethod()
    {
        A a = new A();
        int drawMax = a.drawNumberSetting(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn drawMax into a class level variable and provide a getter\accessor method, like this:

```
private int drawMax;

public void DrawNumberSetting ()
{
    System.out.print ("Please enter the maximum number of draws you want to play: ");
    drawMax = scan.nextInt ();
}

public int getDrawMax()
{
   return drawMax;
}
```